# Cell return to`cellProvider` isn't shown in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, uikit

**I've now filed this to Apple's Feedback Assistant**

I'm using `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference` and the first and second time my `cellProvider` function returns a cell, everything seems to work fine.

However, once an object is updated, so that the cell reloads, the collectionView doesn't actually show the cell that I provided in the `cellProvider` function.

Am I missing something obvious, or does the bug lie out of my hands?

(a projekt with code can be found here as well: https://github.com/everlof/CollectionViewDequeuBug)

I've got a simple core data object, and when a button is pressed, in a UICollectionViewCell's subclass, the object is updated, and triggering a reload of that cell.

However, the cell that's dequeued and returned in the `cellProvider` isn't presented in the collectionView.

See:

```
update(test:) -> <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e668c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ce9ea0>>
Returning dequeued => <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e668c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ce9ea0>>, test test.a => CE10C1C8-400A-47BF-BC7B-D13889A4B893
update(test:) -> <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e668c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ce9ea0>>
Returning dequeued => <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e668c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ce9ea0>>, test test.a => CE10C1C8-400A-47BF-BC7B-D13889A4B893

<trigger update by tapping button>

update(test:) -> <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e72ca0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002cebd40>>
Returning dequeued => <CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e72ca0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002cebd40>>, test test.a => 7A2FC74B-22AB-4608-AF11-852A6191A8D6
```

See? First I get the cell `0x7fd453e668c0`, and then after the update is triggered,  `0x7fd453e72ca0` is dequeued and returned, but it's not shown!

If I open "Debug View Hierarchy", the only cell inside the `CollectionView` is:
`<CollectionViewBug.MyCell: 0x7fd453e668c0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (10 10; 355 100); layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ce9ea0>>`, which actually was the first cell

The simple (CoreData) data object:

```
@objc(Test)
public class Test: NSManagedObject {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Test> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Test>(entityName: "Test")
    }

    @NSManaged public var a: String?
    @NSManaged public var b: String?
}
```

My cell is basically as small as I could make it:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    static let identifier = "MyCell"
    var test: Test?
    let btn = UIButton()
    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        btn.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(btn)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .white

        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func doAction() {
        // Set a new ID
        let testID = test!.objectID
        AppDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { ctx in
            let test = ctx.object(with: testID) as! Test
            test.a = UUID().uuidString
            try! ctx.save()
        }
    }

    func update(test: Test) {
        self.test = test
        print("update(test:) -> \(self)")
        // Update cell's label with new ID
        label.text = test.a
    }

}
```

And lastly, the collectionView:

```
class CollectionView: UICollectionView, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Test>

    var diffableDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference!

    init() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Test> = Test.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Test.a, ascending: true)]
        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController<Test>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                                  managedObjectContext: AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext,
                                                                  sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                                  cacheName: nil)

        let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: NSCollectionLayoutDimension.estimated(100))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitem: item, count: 1)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 10

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

        super.init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier)
        diffableDataSource =
            UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference(collectionView: self, cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, testID in
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
                let test = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext.object(with: testID as! NSManagedObjectID) as! Test
                cell.update(test: test)
                print("Returning dequeued => \(cell), test test.a => \(test.a!)")
                return cell
            }
        )
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func fetch() {
        delegate = self
        dataSource = diffableDataSource
        fetchResultController.delegate = self
        try? fetchResultController.performFetch()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
        diffableDataSource.applySnapshot(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem.  Did you ever learn of a solution?

Comment: After researching the issue some more, our experience of a cell being returned from the diffable datasource that is never displayed I believe is due to the data prefetching that UICollectionView supports.  On my end, two cells are created when I update the data source, and only one cell is ever supposed to be displayed.  

I ended up setting the view controller as the delegate to the UICollectionView and then implementing collectionView(_: willDisplay: forItemAt:) and that would give me access only to the cell that was going to be displayed.

Comment: @mikepj Good info! I don't remember how I solved this, if I found the issue or went with a workaround.